# Maven ,error when build with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

i have a `maven` project and i want to create a `.jar` contain all the dependency

for that i am using `maven-assembly-plugin`

`Maven build`... with `goal` `clean package assembly:single` i get errors like

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] C:\integ\src\main\java\com\woo\bfi\la\ss\batchIntegrator\BatchRunner.java: [11,54] error: package com.ss.ff.ll.dd.bigDataAccessManager does not exist
```

it say that the packeges i imported in the class BatchRunner does not exist

but i can run the application successfully

the plugin in the pom.xml :

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.test.IntegrationTest</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

i know that maybe there are not enough information to solve this but i hope someone had the same problem and solved it

Comment: Have you tried adding executions section? <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>

Comment: it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

try to use this. only `mvn clean package`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <finalName>testXXX</finalName>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.test.IntegrationTest</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>

        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>

        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but i got the same error

Comment: do you have this error,when you run your application or during build?

Comment: just during building ,,,,, actually the packages that can't be found it's packages i created ,,, i mean it's not a external jar's

Comment: if during building i think you have real compilation error you have to resolve it first. so it happening during the compile phase and have no thing to do with assembly packaging. you are not reaching this phase

Comment: do you have all correct dependency in your pom file?

Comment: yes ... and i can run my application without any error